# Keycloak endpoints for user registration, password reset, forgot password etc

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm creating a mobile application that uses a server to store data into. I am also creating web application that will function as a restful database service for my mobile application.

I plan to use Keycloak for my user management and authentication (Oauth2) of my mobile. I understand that Keycloak has an endpoint for user registration but it requires the mobile app to redirect to the keycloak server url. If possible I would like to avoid this and do all the process within the mobile application. Also, I'm unaware of the other endpoints such as password reset and forgot password. Would anyone know?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the admin API to include it in your mobile app. Personally I think this is a bad idea to do it directly on the client, because you need to store the credentials of an admin on the mobile as well. Maybe it is an option for you to have backend application, which handles your password forgot use cases and include it in your mobile app.

This seems to be related to this question: [Is there an API call for changing user password on keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910615/is-there-an-api-call-for-changing-user-password-on-keycloak).

- Admin REST Api: http://keycloak.github.io/docs/rest-api/index.html
- Endpoints for clients: /auth/realms/{client-id}/.well-known/openid-configuration