# Is there an API call for changing user password on keycloak?

Tags: json, keycloak

I am trying to implement my own form for changing a user's password. I tried to find an API for changing a user's password in Keycloak but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.
Is there an API for doing it?

Answer (score 73):

you can use `PUT /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/reset-password`

- {id} is the user id in keycloak  (not the login)

Here is s sample body.

`{ "type": "password", "temporary": false, "value": "my-new-password" }`

Comment: That is what I used in the end but it is admin password override. I was looking for something that doesn't require using the admin privileges.

Comment: Sorry did not find anything like that. I looked for it as well.

Answer (score 40):

### UPDATE Keycloak 12

The solution described below will no longer work in Keycloak Versions 12 or higher as the developers decided to remove all Account Rest APIs [as described in this issue](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7393#issuecomment-773502862).

Thanks to @Radivarig for pointing this out!

---

### Solution for Keycloak 11

Keycloak recently introduced this feature, but it's currently still in preview and therefore not documented.

To make it work, you need to activate the `account_api` feature by starting keycloak with the parameter `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.account_api=enabled` like so:

```
bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.account_api=enabled
```

(source: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#profiles)

After that, you can use `POST /auth/realms/your-realm/account/credentials/password` and provide the http Header `Accept: application/json`. The header will make keycloak use a RestAPI-Service which is accepting and returning JSON (instead of the default form-based one which is only accepting `x-www-form-urlencoded` and returns HTML.)

As **Request-Body**, provide a JSON like this:

```
{
    "currentPassword": "oldPassword",
    "newPassword": "newPassword",
    "confirmation": "newPassword"
}
```

A full example with curl would look like this:

```
curl --request POST 'https://path-to-your-host.com/auth/realms/your-realm/account/credentials/password' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "currentPassword": "oldPassword",
    "newPassword": "newPassword",
    "confirmation": "newPassword"
}'
```

Note that - as written above - this feature is still in preview and might change in the future. So use it with caution!

Comment: I tried it and returns 401. I searched for solutions but still got nothing. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Hm, hard to say without more information. But as you say it is a 401, I'd suspect that the Bearer-Token you are providing might be wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just found out that my bearer token has different iss and it's working well now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sure thing.Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @DavidLosert do you know how to enable this when running Keycloak on Docker? Can't find the right env variable to pass.

Comment: @jeudyx : Depends on which image you are using ;). If it's the official one: According to [the documentation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/README.md#start-a-keycloak-instance-with-custom-command-line-options), you can provide an env Variable `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND`, so I guess you could use it like: `docker run -e JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.account_api=enabled" jboss/keycloak`

Comment: That's super helpful @DavidLosert ! sometimes one can get lost in the docs. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, the API works fine but can you provide us  the documentation or the commit link

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. I use version 11.x.

Comment: @MalekZarkouna : I found this solution by looking at the code of keycloak. AFAIK there is no documentation about this and I couldn't find any issue. I'd have to google it myself now - sorry :/

Comment: Which other API provided by account-API? Please share the API doc link if possible
I need API to update profile info and get logged sessions.

Comment: @NitinVavdiya: As written one comment above - I don't know if there is any API Documentation. I looked at the code itself to find that out and thats was also almost 6 months ago now - so I'd have to search and google myself for it now, sorry :/

Comment: I checked their documents there is no API doc.

Comment: Is this endpoint still working? When I try to call it I get `"error": "RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header"` Note: using `POST /auth/realms/your-realm/account` to change the profile is working.

Comment: I don't know about V12, didn't try ith out yet. But have you enabled the account_api as descibred above?

Comment: I'm running it dockerized, and I added the `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.account_api=enabled"` environment variable. Is there a way to verify whether it is really enabled?

Comment: when starting the docker , check logs you will see account_api preview enabled

Comment: Indeed, with Keycloak 11.0.3 I see `Preview feature enabled: account_api`, but starting Keycloak 12.0.2 with the same parameters this section is missing from the log. It seems that either they removed the accunt_api, or they changed the way to enable it.

Comment: I also get 405, on both version 12.0.2 and 12.0.3 but `account_api` is anabled by default in Keycloak 12.0.3 from this commit: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/6b2e1cbc5f343c79687da5f494f8af995f9ca1f0

Comment: Endpoints were removed and direct password change is no longer supported https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7393#issuecomment-773502862

Comment: @Radivarig: Thanks so much for pointing this out. I updated the answer above so people will not have to learn it the hard way as you did.

Comment: the following change password API is not working for me. my keycloak version is 20 and it is dockerized container. If you know the answer let me know

Comment: As written in the comment above and in the answer itselfs, this only worked up until Keycloak 11, as they removed the necessary APIs in Keycloak 12. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 37):

Rather than specifying a new password manually a better security practice is to use the

`PUT /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email`

admin call with `"UPDATE_PASSWORD"` as the required action. This causes Keycloak to send an email to the user that gives a magic link for the user to set a new password.

Note: {id} is the user id in keycloak (not the login)

Comment: You are right, but there are still a few users, who prefer to get the password told by phone and then be forced to change it instead of searching for an email.

Comment: @ChristianKaiser Keycloak doesn't support flows that aren't secure, in your case someone knows the user's password for a while

Comment: @shonky, Is there any way to modify Keycloak's email template?

Comment: @Dreamer yes, but it would be best to ask a specific question rather than hijack the this one. Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057786/keycloak-freemarker-email

Comment: Example for a use-case, where this is useful: I'm building an email service where people login using OIDC via Keycloak. If the user has his account email address on the email service, then sending a link to the email address will not solve the issue, since the user doesn't have access to the account. In this situation I would establish an alternative authentication mechanism (e.g. something like backup codes) in the mail service UI which eventually sets the user password to a temporary password in Keycloak and forces a password change upon next login.

Answer (score 10):

As [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html) suggests you can send a `PUT` requqest to `keycloakEndpoint/auth/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email` to execute actions against user. you need to obtain an admin access token as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283281/how-to-activate-the-rest-api-of-keycloak)[image]

Comment: Is there any documentation available for the 'actions' parameter? What to put there?

Comment: @HassanRaza I found a list in javadoc of UserResource: `VERIFY_EMAIL, UPDATE_PROFILE, CONFIGURE_TOTP, UPDATE_PASSWORD, TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS`. It's probably not complete but couldn't find any other official documentation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: The better way to do it via web app

```
keycloak.login({
    action: "UPDATE_PASSWORD",
})
```

For more info: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#login-options

Comment: Can you give an curl example?

Comment: That's a method from the JS library (Keycloak Client Adapter)

Comment: this should be the top answer. no point in trying to implement your own messy password change with the admin API when keycloak literally providers a flow for you.

Answer (score 4):

:-)

```
#!/bin/bash
#CHANGE ADMIN PASSWORD

apt update
apt install -y curl jq

KEYCLOAK_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:8080
ADMIN_USER_OLD_PASSWORD=
ADMIN_USER_NEW_PASSWORD=
TOKEN=$(curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d "username=admin&password=$ADMIN_USER_OLD_PASSWORD&client_id=admin-cli&grant_type=password" "$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" | jq -r ".access_token" ;)
ADMIN_USER_ID=$(curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H 'Accept: application/json' "$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/master/users" | jq -r '.[] | select(.username=="admin") | .id' )
curl -s -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H 'Accept: application/json' "$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/master/users/$ADMIN_USER_ID/reset-password" -d "{\"type\":\"password\",\"value\":\"$ADMIN_USER_NEW_PASSWORD\",\"temporary\":false}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   constructor(
        private keycloakService: KeycloakService,
        ) { }
    
    onPasswordChangeButtonClick(){
      this.keycloakService.login({
          action: "UPDATE_PASSWORD",
      });
    }
```

please try this approach to change the password

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Here at SO code only answers are **not considered good answers**, though, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7393#issuecomment-1103532595

But you have to see if you can use a custom theme, if you want a different form than the default from keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set_user_password function of class keycloak_admin to reset a normal user password.

Example:

```
keycloak_admin = keycloak_login("YOUR REALM NAME")
keycloak_admin.set_user_password(user_id, password, temporary=False)
```

Used function:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin for keycloak_login  (To import this install keycloak lib)
```

Answer (score -1):

No, OAuth and OpenID Connect protocols doesn't define such feature and Keycloak also doesn't have ability to do this on user's behalf. There is a server-to-Server Admin API that alows to change the user's password or reset it but you can't call it from GUI.
But the Keycloak provides some kind of "My Account Page" by url like `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/your-realm/account/` - replace `your-realm` part of URL and just redirect a user to it.
[image: Keucloak My User Account Service: change password]

In documentation it called [User Account Service](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html#user-account-service)

Also if you use auto discovery you can obtain the url by reading `account-service` from JSON by URL `http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/your-realm`

Comment: Keycloak does provide an API which is authenticated through a token.