# jHipster: How works new user module with Keycloak for a simple user in production?

Tags: oauth-2.0, user-controls, openid, jhipster, keycloak

I install new version of jHipster with OAuth and Keycloak. I did not know Keycloak end it seemed very cool.

I have a standalone instalation (not jHipster Docker) with mysql and works fine (i import data from jhipster-users-0.json and jhipster-realm.json) and i see all data in database tables.

**My questions are:**

- How the real user will operate things how "Change Passw", "Forgot Passw", "Change Name"... I dont see this informations in web of application and i think the web of keycloak is for administrator e not for simple users.
- In old application, i associates jhi_user with my main class, for build something similar a multi tenant. Now i see jhi_user table but the users are in keycloak.user_entity and the page crud of my main class see only my jhipster schema. How i resolve this?

If anyone can help me I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, there's the chance to add the forgot password link in the realm's login page. Remember [you can implement a theme](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#creating-a-theme) according to your needs for this page:

[image]

Keycloak also has an API (the administration web is based in it), which you can use to make operations. [There's an endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355313/1199132) to send an e-mail for password recovery: `PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email`.

For your second question, you've got two options. The ideal thing is to make keycloak manage your users. You can manage them [using the API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.0/rest-api/index.html), through your application. Otherwise, if you want to store them in your application DB, you can still write an implementation of [custom user storage SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi), to load them from DB or from some API you might provide in your application:

> You can use the User Storage SPI to write extensions to Keycloak to
>   connect to external user databases and credential stores. The built-in
>   LDAP and ActiveDirectory support is an implementation of this SPI in
>   action. Out of the box, Keycloak uses its local database to create,
>   update, and look up users and validation credentials. Often though,
>   organizations have existing external proprietary user databases that
>   they cannot migrate to Keycloak’s data model. For those situations,
>   application developers can write implementations of the User Storage
>   SPI to bridge the external user store and the internal user object
>   model that Keycloak uses to log in users and manage them.