# How can I create a client_credential account in to be able to perform administrative tasks?

Tags: postman, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, clientcredential

I'm trying to achieve the [same exact thing of this user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275885/1538384) but using a client with client_credentials

I've followed [this post](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/keycloak-client-credentials-grant-example/) to create my client with client credentials grant and so I can get the access token like this

[image]

but when I try to call the [execute-action-email api](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/10.0/rest-api/index.html#_executeactionsemail) I only get an error 401

[image]

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the token from a user with the correct permissions for instance the master admin:

```
curl -k -sS     -d "client_id=admin-cli"
                -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME"
                -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD"
                -d "grant_type=password"
                http://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token)
```

Alternatively, what you can do is:

- Create a new client you the master Realm;
- Configured as with grant type client credentials;
- Go to Mappers;
- Click on [Create]
- As Mapper Type select "Hardcoded Role"
- Click on Select Role and selection "admin"
- Save;
- Ask a token using the newly created client.