# Can't create Role using Keycloak REST API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to add a Role to my realm in Keycloak but it's giving me a bad request response. My steps:

1. Get a token using:

```
 curl -X POST "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \                                                                 
 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 -d 'username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli'
```

2. Get the client ID using:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/clients?clientId=my-client \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer "$access_token \
 -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

3. Try to add the Role using [documentation][1]:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/my-realm/clients/[ID-from-above]/roles \
 -H "Content-Type: application.json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer "$access_token --data '{"name":"test-role"}'
```

When I issue the last command I get a bad request response. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_roles_resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be pretty close.

I was able to make realm level roles by following REST API:

[image]

The difference between this and your call is that you are trying to make a client level role. Do you have a specific requirement for client level role or were you just trying out?

If Realm level roles fulfill your requirement, you can use above API.

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53292944/2458858) to make sure you have followed steps correctly to set up admin Rest API.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the token with the client-secret from the client you want to access.

```
token=$(
  curl -X POST "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'username=[USER]&password=[PASSWORD]&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]' \
  | jq -r '.access_token'
)

clientID=$(
  curl -X GET "http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/vertical/clients?clientId=[CLIENT_NAME]" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer "${token} \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' | jq -r '.[].id'
)
```

Try to use "application/json" instead of "application.json".
Quotes from Authorization header should include the token.

Dont forget the -X POST in your last curl command :)

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/[REALM]/clients/${clientID}/roles" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
 -d '{"name": "test-role"}'
```