# How can I update a Keycloak password from the REST API (PUT method)?

Tags: rest, api, postman, keycloak, put

I set up a keycloak server with LDAP users to take advantage of the SSO on my applications.
I would like to change the password of the logged in user on my application through the Keycloak API. So, in the future, my Angular application will be able to make a request to the keycloak API to change the password of the logged-in user.

So I tried to do what is indicated in the documentation (method PUT, reset-password) but without success ...
I did my tests with postman, I wonder if my token is the one to be used? Does the problem come from elsewhere?

I have this url :
`PUT`  `{url}/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id user}/reset-password/`

I have this header :

`Content-type` `application/json`

i have this body :

```
{
    "pass" : {
        "type": "password",
        "temporary": false,
        "value": "my-new-password"
    }
}
```

I get a 401 error if I did not try to renew the token quickly (which makes me say that the problem may not come from the token) and I get a 403 or 400 error when I got a new token via postman oAuth 2.0

I sometimes get this message:

`Unrecognized field "pass" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.CredentialRepresentation), not marked as ignorable`

Please, help me !

You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rs6x.jpg) my autorization in postman, i don't know what is "State"

Comment: :-) try this and let us know... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71091248/8605229

Answer (score 5):

Body of `PUT` Should be CredentialRepresentation, which is

```
{
  "type":"password",
  "value":"my-new-password",
  "temporary":false
}
```

Comment: Just tested this and it is the only option despite what official documentations suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You can use POST method with these parametes:

URL:

```
http://[Server Address]/auth/admin/realms/[Realm Name]/users
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type application/json
```

Body:

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "credentials": [{
        "type": "password",
        "value": "123456",
        "temporary": false
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change pass to credentials.

it’s better to check current password to increase the security