# How does a client need to be set up for the account_api to work?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to use the Keycloak account API to implement a password change form, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61388281/1058828.  But I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error.

I [looked at the code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/e2040f5d132a08efb2ef8acd24d1b85a2a2d5e3d/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/account/AccountCredentialResource.java#L371), and it seems the user needs the `manage-account` role, but I'm not sure how to configure the client appropriately.

How do I give users the role?  And is there any further set-up I need to do to make the API work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after setting roles for users, users could change passwords, create accounts ...
T settings like this:
Step 1: login adminconsole keycloak
Step 2: select the user tab> view all user> edit the user you need> select the role mappings> Client Client Roles> enter realm-management> select manager-user> add selected> done and test it again? Good luck!